# replace " ' " (aphostrophe) with "," (comma) in 2'442'031.67

Tags: java

Need to Replace " ' " with ", "

```
String[] word = {"2'442'031.67" , "9'031.67" , "79'442'031.67", "delivered"}   
char a = '\'';
for(int j=0;j< word.length() ;j++) {
    if(word.charAt(j)==a) {
        System.out.println("Insideflag"+word.charAt(j));
        word.replaceAll(a, ",")
    }
}
```

but getting inline eval '' error.

Comment: Can you tag a language you're using?

Comment: And format your code as code

Comment: Please could you [edit] your code to include 1) the language you're using; 2) the *exact* error you're getting; 3) the result of the debugging output you seem to have added,

Comment: if(word.charAt(j)==a) is wrong, it does that: take the word at position j from the array and take the letter at position j in the word and check if it is \'

Comment: I've tagged as Java because `System.out.println()` is all the Java I can remember from my 2002 course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also choose to use the regex `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes to achieve this. You update the array items with the new values as follows:

```
String[] word = {"2'442'031.67" , "9'031.67" , "79'442'031.67", "delivered"};
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("'");
for(int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(word[i]);
    word[i] = matcher.replaceAll(",");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Java:

```
for (String myWord : word) {
    String newWord = myWord.replaceAll("'", ",");
    // now do something with newWord
}
```

OR

```
for (String myWord : word) {
    if (myWord.contains("'")) {
        String newWord = myWord.replaceAll("'", ",");
        // now do something with newWord
    }
}
```

Comment: You could do it in a different way: You could parse the number with the right formatter and format it the needed way. That would replace the ' with , as well.